# Create Cookie ASP.NET & MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a quite simple problem. I want to create a cookie at a Client, that is created by the server.
I've found a lot of [pages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244904/Cookies-in-ASP-NET) that describe, how to use it - but I always stuck at the same point.

I have a `DBController` that gets invoked when there is a request to the DB.

The `DBController`'s constructor is like this:

```
public class DBController : Controller
{
    public DBController()
    {
        HttpCookie StudentCookies = new HttpCookie("StudentCookies");
        StudentCookies.Value = "hallo";
        StudentCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(StudentCookies);
        Response.Flush();
    }

    [... more code ...]

}
```

I get the Error "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" at:

```
StudentCookies.Expire = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

This is a kind of a basic error message. So what kind of basic thing I've forgot?

Comment: I suspect that `Response` is null in the controller constructor. It get's set later on. Try your code in an action method.

Comment: Ya @Jim it works inside action method

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is you cannot add to the response in constructor of the controller. The Response object has not been created, so it is getting a null reference, try adding a method for adding the cookie and calling it in the action method. Like so:

```
private HttpCookie CreateStudentCookie()
{
    HttpCookie StudentCookies = new HttpCookie("StudentCookies");
    StudentCookies.Value = "hallo";
    StudentCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    return StudentCookies;
}

//some action method
Response.Cookies.Add(CreateStudentCookie());
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `Response.SetCookie()`, because `Response.Cookie.Add()` can add multiple cookies, whereas `SetCookie()` will update an existing cookie.
So I think your problem can be solved.

```cs
public DBController()
{
    HttpCookie StudentCookies = new HttpCookie("StudentCookies");
    StudentCookies.Value = "hallo";
    StudentCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    Response.SetCookie(StudentCookies);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Using your method too 'System.NullReferenceException' occurs at line     Response.SetCookie(StudentCookies);

Comment: In reference to [Jim's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/231821/jim) comment, your provided code doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Response.Cookies["StudentCookies"].Value = "hallo";
```

to update existing cookie.

Comment: It looks like in .Net core is now:
```Response.Cookies.Append("StudentCookies", "hallo");```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Initialize()` method of the controller instead of the constructor. 
In the initialize function the `Request` object is available. I suspect that the same action can be taken with the `Response`object.